# loop over list defined with newcommand

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, foreach, pgffor

I try to automate generating same tables.
With a `\newcommand` a comma separated list of filenames is defined.
I want to iterate over these files, import them and concat them to a single table.
Sounds easy, but I fail.

Reading the manual of pgfplotstable, it offers 3 approaches.

- `\foreach` : is grouped, such that the output defined within the loop is not accessible from the outside.
- `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` : seems especially designed for that task. It is ungrouped and the example in the manual nearly works for me.
  But is only works if I explicit define the list. Not if I declare the list elsewhere with `\newcommand`.

  The problem: It does not iterate over the entries. Just one iteration with `\filename` being the whole string of all filenames.
- `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` : same as `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, just slightly changed syntax.

I can think of two approaches, but can't solve them.

- Use `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` with working external list
- use `\foreach` and somehow write the output to be globally accessible

What can/should i do?

---

Here is my current test environment.

```
\newcommand*\fileList{List1.csv,List2.csv}

\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{List1.csv}
A B
1 2
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{List2.csv}
A B
3 4
    \end{filecontents}  

\begin{document}

% % % This works fine
\begin{center}\bfseries
    Test with pgfplotsforeachungrouped and explicit list
\end{center}

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \filename in {List1.csv,List2.csv} {%
    <\filename> %debug output
    \pgfplotstableread{\filename}{\temptable} %read file
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\output}{\temptable} %append file
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\temptable} %debug output
    \hfill %debug output
}%
Output : \pgfplotstabletypeset{\output} %debug output
\pgfplotstableclear{\output} %clear \output

% % % This does not work
\begin{center}\bfseries
    Test with pgfplotsforeachungrouped and external list
\end{center}

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \filename in {\fileList} {%
    <\filename> 
}
% Outputs <List1.csv,List2.csv>

% % % This does not work
\begin{center}\bfseries
    Test with pgfplotsforeachungrouped and external list
\end{center}
Package pgfplots Error: Found unexpected characters: expected 'in '.

%\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \filename in \fileList {%
%   <\filename> %debug output
%}

% this works
\begin{center}\bfseries
    Test with pgfplotsinvokeforeach and explicit list
\end{center}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{List1.csv,List2.csv}{ %
    <#1>
}

%
%
%
\begin{center}\bfseries
    Tests with foreach and external list
\end{center}
\foreach \filename in \fileList{ %
    <\filename> %debug output
    \pgfplotstableread{\filename}{\temptable} %read file
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\output}{\temptable} %append file
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\temptable} %debug output
    \hfill %debug output
}%
% \output is not defined


\foreach \filename in {\fileList}{ %
    <\filename>
    % Outputs <List1.csv,List2.csv>
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `\fileList` is not expanded. The different syntax of `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` is useful here. Add two `\expandafter`s and it works with your `\fileList`.

```
\newcommand*\fileList{List1.csv,List2.csv}

\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{List1.csv}
A B
1 2
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{List2.csv}
A B
3 4
    \end{filecontents}  

\begin{document}

% this works
\begin{center}\bfseries
    Test with pgfplotsinvokeforeach and some \verb|\expandafter|\,s
\end{center}
\expandafter\pgfplotsinvokeforeach\expandafter{\fileList}{ %
    <#1>
    \pgfplotstableread{#1}{\temptable} %read file
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\output}{\temptable} %append file
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\temptable} %debug output
    \hfill %debug output
}
Output : \pgfplotstabletypeset{\output} %debug output
\end{document}
```