Why is \pgfkeyssetvalue not working within a \foreach environment?
I want to understand why \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\cellcolor{lightgray}#1} is working outside of a \foreach loop, but not within.
In my MWE, I prepared both scenarios. You just need to comment out the first line of \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\cellcolor{lightgray}#1} as described in the comments. I would expect, that in both scenarios the descriptions of TypeA are colored up light gray. (The \def\testArray{{element1}} has no purpose in this MWE and is just there to feed the loop.)
MWE
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
  Type,Description
  typA,description0
  typB,description1
  typA,description2
  typA,description2
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}


\def\testArray{{element1}}

% Color up all cells
\newcommand{\colorLines}[1]{
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%THIS WORKS!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Comment me out to test!
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\cellcolor{lightgray}#1}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach \elementX in \testArray {
       %%%%%%%%%%%%%THIS DOESN'T WORK!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\cellcolor{lightgray}#1}
       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    }
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  every column/.style={
    assign cell content/.code={
       \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Type}\of{\csvdata}
       \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{typA}}{
           \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Description}}{
                \colorLines{##1}
           }{}
       }{}
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}

RESULT WITH THE LINE ABOVE THE LOOP (This is the wished result)

RESULT WITHOUT THE LINE ABOVE THE LOOP

How can I color up the lines within the \foreach environment?

\foreach creates a group and so you basically have a brace group around your command. (Yes it is a bit of a pain, pgfplots I think has an ungrouped variant).

@UlrikeFischer I thought about something like this, but was wondering that #1 is still valid within the loop. Anyway, can I solve this issue with any trick?

well as I said pgfplots has some ungrouped variants, but the handling is a bit curious, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386567/2388. Personnally I would use one of the expl 3 mapping commands, e.g. \ExplSyntaxOn\newcommand{\colorLines}[1]{\clist_map_inline:Nn\testArray{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell~content}{\cellcolor{lightgray}#1}}}\ExplSyntaxOff.

@UlrikeFischer Ok, I found a workaround for me, because I‘m not very familar with expl3 and I definitely need the “element“ from the loop, which seems not to be given within pgfplot loop. Now i just store the important information temporary and format the cells outside of the loop. Thanksfor the support!

By replacing \foreach with \pgfplotsinvokeforeach section 8.1 Utility Commands in the pgfplots documentation.
%\foreach \elementX in \testArray {
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach \testArray {%<<--- modif here

Code
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
  Type,Description
  typA,description0
  typB,description1
  typA,description2
  typA,description2
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}


\def\testArray{{element1}}

% Color up all cells
\newcommand{\colorLines}[1]{
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%THIS WORKS!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Comment me out to test!
    %\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\cellcolor{lightgray}#1}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\foreach \elementX in \testArray {
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach \testArray {%<<--- modif here
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%THIS DOESN'T WORK!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\cellcolor{lightgray}#1}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    }
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  every column/.style={
    assign cell content/.code={
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Type}\of{\csvdata}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{typA}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Description}}{
                \colorLines{##1}
          }{}
      }{}
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}

